Polygons with unit length sides and rational vertices
Consider an $n$-sided polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that every side is length one, and each vertex of the polygon has rational coordinates. For which values of $n \geq 3$ is this construction possible?
It is impossible for $n=3$, and possible for $n=4$, but what about $n=5$ or higher values?

You can definitely do any even $n$ if the successive sides don't have to constitute a new direction.

Actually, even  with required  turns. $(0,0),(1,0),(8/5,4/5),(1,8/5),(0,8/5),(-3/4,4/5),(0,0)$ works for $n=6.$ You can even ensure the polygons is convex when $n$ is even. The hard part is odd $n.$

It is a "well-known problem" that odd $n$ is not possible. Scale it up minimally to integer coordinates, show that the length is odd, then show that the parity changes imply we have an even number of sides.
